# Carerra Hellcat - Front Derailleur issues - Possibly replace

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front

I am new here and to cycling as an adult (last time I rode I was a teenager some 30 years ago).

I have bought a second hand Hellcat and am having issues with the front derailleur (FD). It sort of works now (won't go into the detail) but having read a few posts it is clear what the issue is - incompatibility.

The bike uses SRAM gear changing equipment however the FD is Shimano (Tourney). I have looked high and low for a SRAM x4 FD but with no luck so the next step would be to potentially buy a different setup for the changer and FD. It is a 3x8 bike so would need something to suit. Also, what parts do I buy as I have zero knowledge of what to get (as I believe some FD's are suited to road bikes only). It doesnt need to be pro-spec, I am simply riding for health rather than competition.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is as the front derailleur is absolutely compatible. It is the rear derailleur where the subtle differences are important. As a side note, the industry jokes that SRAM 1x systems are so good because they never managed to make a decent front derailleur.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily the case that your problems are caused by equipment incompatibility. Bikes have been specced by manufacturers with mixed drivetrains. And front derailleurs are a lot less sensitive to compatibility problems than rears.

In any case, it would be helpful to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: FDs, especially from 30-year-old bikes are quite crude pieces of equipment and have undergone little evolution until recently. So there isn't normally a compatibility issue when replacing it with something more recent. You'll just need one of the type that came with your bike: three ring, bottom-pull or top-pull, clamped mount or braze-on mount.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question not an answer